# What's the best way for an iOS app to retrieve its URL scheme?

Tags: ios

If your app has different targets with corresponding different URL schemes (ex. `blackbox://meta`, `blackbox-alpha://meta`) you may find yourself wanting to dynamically look up the current app's scheme at run-time. How can you do that?

The following does **NOT** work:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleURLSchemes"]
```

Answer (score 3):

The URL schemes array is actually stored under the *URL Types* array. Assuming you only have one URL type and the first listed scheme is the one you're after:

Objective-C

```
NSArray *urlTypes = [NSBundle.mainBundle objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleURLTypes"];
NSArray *urlSchemes = [urlTypes firstObject][@"CFBundleURLSchemes"];
NSString *urlScheme = [urlSchemes firstObject];
```

Swift

```
let urlTypes = NSBundle.mainBundle.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleURLTypes") as! [[String:Any]]
let urlSchemes = urlTypes.first?["CFBundleURLSchemes"]! as! [String]
let urlScheme2 = urlSchemes.first
```